# Infinite recursion with Serialization Jackson on @ManyToMany - Only in relation when using Database calls

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson, objectmapper

currently i am working on a project, where i use EntityBeans (Hibernate) for Database Access and using Jackson ObjectMapper for Mapping those Objects to Pojo for UI.

To test those mappings and the results, i am writing for each layer several test:

1. Layer 0 Test: Simple conversion (okay)
2. Layer 1 Test: Conversion of the Structure, where objects having
   relations (okay)
3. Layer 2 Test: Same as Layer 1, but this time with persistence - here
   the error occurs.
4. Layer 3 Test: (at this point irrelevant)

As a solution, I did not want to use @JsonBackreference and @JsonManagedReference on the @ManyToMany Relations, i need those infos on both objects. For the @ManyToOne and @OneToMany relation no problem occurs.

One solution would maybe write a custom converter, but i want to understand the problem here.

The Structure is as follows:

Product-Class

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id", scope = Company.class)
public class Product extends ProductBase {

// some more unrelated
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_manufacturer")
    private Company manufacturer;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "supplierProducts")
    private Set<Company> supplier = new HashSet<>();
// .. some more unrelated
}
```

Pojo-Class

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id", scope = Company.class)
public class ProductPojo extends ProductBase {

//.. some unrelated stuff

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private CompanyPojo manufacturer;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Set<CompanyPojo> supplier = new HashSet<>();


//.. more..

}
```

On the Company Object we have:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id", scope = Product.class)
public class Company extends CompanyBase {
// .. other fields
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_product_manufacturer")
    private Set<Product> manufacturerProducts = new HashSet<>();

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "supplier_products",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fk_company_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fk_product_id")})
    private Set<Product> supplierProducts = new HashSet<>();
// .. other fields
}
```

and it's counter-part:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id", scope = Company.class)
public class CompanyPojo extends CompanyBase {
//.. code
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Set<ProductPojo> manufacturerProducts = new HashSet<>();

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Set<ProductPojo> supplierProducts = new HashSet<>();
//.. as usual, some more code...
}
```

Evaluation of the debugger shows this:

Debuger-Eval without DB-Access and successfully converting objects:

[image: Working conversion: Converting solely on Objects itself, without db access (Product and ProductPojo is shown)]

Debuger-Eval with DB-Access and failing converting objects:

[image: Fail conversion: Converting with / after DB Access (Product is shown)]

Last but not least, the error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: de.bloise.data.persistence.unities.Company["supplierProducts"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->de.bloise.data.persistence.product.Product["supplier"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->de.bloise.data.persistence.unities.Company["supplierProducts"]->.....
```

I have no idea and i don't see any difference between those objects. It would be easier to understand if both would fail to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after evaluating different mapping tools, and making thoughs on this topic, i could really not understand why the layer 1 test do run, but not the layer 2 test.

However, using different mapper (orika did not work because of java 17), but using mapstruct and it's default, the result were the same, as expected.

The proper solution, which takes a slight more effort, is simply to add on one of these @ManyToMany associations the @JsonIgnore Attribute.
Now, when a transfer via Rest is required, i simply added a query on Company-Repository, like this:

```
Set<Company> findCompaniesBySupplierProductsContaining(final Product product);
```

With this approach, i can load them for products seperatly, serialize them and add the Set of Company to the product requested.

However, i am still curious why the 2nd Level test does not fall into this StackOverflow.